# Query in Perl Subroutines

Tags: perl, subroutine

I've to use perl as a part of our internship, I've come across this piece of code and could not understand what this may mean.

```
$val->ReadSim($first_sim, \&DataProcessing);
```

In the script, subroutine DataProcessing is defined, but could not find ReadSim. I tried searching in our infrastructure but was not able to. This was given to me to understand a week ago and I can't ask the guide without losing credits...

Please help...

Comment: `$val` must be defined somewhere. It is an object of some kind. Find the place it is defined, and you find your answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're seeing is not a mere subroutine, but a *method* on some *object* called `$val`.

I take it you might see something on top of the program like this:

```
use Foo::Bar;   # Some Perl module
```

This Perl module will contain the *method* ReadSim. Somewhere in your code, you probably see something like this:

```
my $val = Foo::Bar->new;   # If the people who wrote this followed standards...
```

This *defines* `$val` as an object of `Foo::Bar`. If you look in package `Foo::Bar`, you'd see something like this:

```
#! Foo/Bar.pm

package Foo::Bar;
use strict;  # Because I'm an optimist
use warnings;

...


sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    ...
    my $self = {};
    ...
    bless $self, $class;
    ...
    return $self;   # May simply be bless {}, $class;
}
```

Then further down, you'll see:

```
sub ReadSim {
    my $self = shift;
    ...
}
```

The `$self = {}` is a *reference* to a Perl hash. This is how most *objects* are defined. That's pretty much all the *constructor* does. It defines a reference to something, then *blesses* it as that object type. Then, the *methods* are merely subroutines that take the defined object and manipulate that.

```
$val-> ReadSim(...);
```

is equivalent to:

```
Foo::Bar::ReadSim( $val, ... );
```

---

So much for your introduction to Object Oriented Perl by Fire. You still have a question about what does `ReadSim` mean.

If all is right in the world, the developer of that *module* should have created built in Perl documentation called *POD*. First, determine the type of object `$val` is. Look where `$val` is defined (Something like `my $val = Foo::Bar->new(...);`). The `Foo::Bar` is the *class* that `$val` is a member of. You can do this from the command line:

```
$ perldoc Foo::Bar
```

And, if you're lucky, you'll see the documentation for `Foo::Bar` printed out. If you're really, really lucky, you will also see the what `ReadSim` also does.

And, if you're not so lucky, you'll have to do some digging. You can do this:

```
$ perldoc -l Foo::Bar
/usr/perl/lib/perl5/5.12/Foo/Bar.pm
```

This will print out the location of where the *Perl Module* resides on your system. For example, in this case, the module's code is in `/usr/perl/lib/perl5/5.12/Foo/Bar.pm`. Now, you can use an editor on this file to read it, and search for `sub ReadSim` and find out what that <strike>subroutine</strike> ... I mean method does.

---

One final thing. If you're new to Perl, you may want to look at a few tutorials that come with Perl. One is the [Perl Reference Tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html). This tutorial will tell you about references. In standard Perl, there are three different types of variables: scalar, hashes, and arrays. To create more complex data structures, you can create hashes of hashes or hashes of arrays, or arrays of arrays, etc. This tutorial will teach you about how to do this.

Once you understand references, you should read the tutorial on [Perl Object Oriented Programming](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlootut.html). Object Oriented Perl uses references to create a *simulated* world object oriented programming design. (I say *simulated* because some people will argue that Object Oriented Perl isn't really object oriented since you don't have things like private methods and variables. To me, if you can think in terms of objects and methods as you program, it's object oriented).

Comment: ++ good answer. An improvement would be to mention what could be going on if Foo::Bar *does not* define a sub called `ReadSim`. `ReadSim` might be inherited (`@ISA`), or perhaps an `AUTOLOAD` method is defined somewhere.

Comment: @tobyink. You're right about `@ISA` (or `use parent/base;`). And, there's `Class::Struct` and `Moose`. I should have mentioned `Data::Dumper` or `ref` which can help figure out what type of class `$val` is. I'm hoping that `ReadSim` is found, and if not, I'll have to dive even deeper into Perl OOP.